# Centos 6.6 shell script -syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

Here is the shell script code, when i used in the centos 6.6, it will got two error message....

```
./script12.bash: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `$1'
./script12.bash: line 11: `case $1 in'
```

Can you help me find the error?

```
#! /bin/bash
num=0
until [ "$num" -eq 30 ]
do
　　 echo -n "Please input a number here : "
　　 read num

　　 if [ "$num" -gt 30 ] ; then
　　　　echo "$num" is too big , try again.
　　　　echo
　　 elif [ "$num" -eq 30 ] ; then
　　　　echo BINGO !! you got it.
　　 else
　　　　echo "$num" is too small , try again.
　　　　echo
　　 fi
done
```

Comment: Try running the script with line 11 changed to `echo "BINGO !! you got it"`. It appears that the `!!` is being evaluated as a history expansion, although that feature should be off in a non-interactive shell. You may have it turned on somehow, but making the proposed edit should help determine if that is the case.

Comment: The error message refers to the line `case $1 in`, which doesn't exist in the code you posted. The error is coming from somewhere else. Also, you shouldn't have a space in your shebang line (it should be `#!/bin/bash`).

Comment: @Jordan: that space is fine (as long at is is a normal ascii space anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how but your script contains strange blank characters, a hex editor shows ASCII code 80 characters, which seem to confuse bash. When replacing them with normal spaces (ASCII code 20), the following works:

```
#!/bin/bash

num=0
until [ "$num" -eq 30 ]
do
    echo -n "Please input a number here : "
    read num

    if [ "$num" -gt 30 ] ; then
        echo "$num" is too big , try again.
        echo
    elif [ "$num" -eq 30 ] ; then
        echo BINGO !! you got it.
    else
        echo "$num" is too small , try again.
        echo
    fi
done
```